# Storing local dynamic_pointer_cast<>() in outer scope

Tags: pointers, c++11, shared-ptr

In the following piece of code, I'm retrieving a `shared_ptr<A>` from a function. I then dynamically cast the pointer to a deriving class and store it in a `shared_ptr<B>`. The original pointer is **not** a `nullptr`.

```
shared_ptr<B> storage = nullptr;

if (...)
{
  shared_ptr<A> definition = getSharedPointer();

  // Store the lambda
  storage = dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(definition);
}
```

I would expect the `dynamic_pointer_cast` and storage to `storage` to increase the total reference count to 2. Then, when I leave the scope of the if-statement, `storage`'s reference count should be one.

Yet, when I tried to call a method on storage, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS, implying I'm reading in a deleted pointer.

```
storage->foo(...)->bar(...);
```

Is my logic wrong? Is this a bug in clang (can't imagine)?

**EDIT**

I seem to have found the error, which has nothing to do with the pointers. The function `bar()` actually gave the problem. If anyone ever reads this: the above code is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This example works fine:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f7d1864d0942d57c40b255db78e79e3d-e1204655eaff68246b392dc70c5a32c9)

```
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct A {
    virtual ~A() {}
};
struct B : A {};

shared_ptr<A> getSharedPointer() {
    return make_shared<B>();
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    shared_ptr<B> storage = nullptr;

    if (true)
    {
      shared_ptr<A> definition = getSharedPointer();

      // Store the lambda
      storage = dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(definition);
    }

    cout << storage.get() << endl;
}
```

It would seem that your `shared_ptr<A>` is not pointing to a `B` and the result of the `dynamic_pointer_cast` is `nullptr`. Maybe a debugging statement would be helpful:

```
if (...)
{
  shared_ptr<A> definition = getSharedPointer();
  cerr << "as A: " << definition.get()
       << ", as B: " << dynamic_cast<B>(definition.get()) << endl;

  // Store the lambda
  storage = dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(definition);
}
```

Comment: Huh? That is extremely weird. I have walked through the entire path in my debugger and I'm certain what comes out of `getSharedPointer()` is a `B` (allocated with new and passed into a `shared_ptr<>`). I can see it happening.

Comment: @Frishert `dynamic_cast` requires RTTI, which will only be there if the base class has a virtual member - do `A` and `B` share a base with a virtual member? (sorry to belabor the obvious)

Comment: No problem @Casey, bugs are always in places you deem obviously correct. In any case: yes, all classes in the hierarchy have a virtual method (the destructor). Your debugging statement outputs the same addresses.

Comment: In fact: even when I `cerr << storage.get() << endl;` in the outer scope, the addresses are the same.

Comment: I found the source, see the edit in the post. Turns out the problem wasn't with shared_ptr at all; a stupid mistake. I apologize if I wasted your time, Casey.